# How do I set these divs to bottom & top of container?

Tags: html, css

Im creating a horizontal slider but im kinda confused with these divs positions. It shows up different between firefox & chrome browsers.

[image]

```
            /* This should be aligned to top */
            .img {
                border: 1px solid blue;
                height: 85%;
            }

            /* This should be aligned to bottom */
            .views {
                height: 15%;
                border: 1px solid green;
            }



            <table>
            <tr>
                <td><div class="img">any image</div><div class="views">3500 views</div></td>                
                <td><div class="img">any image</div><div class="views">2990 views</div></td>                
                <td><div class="img">any image</div><div class="views">1678 views</div></td>                
                <td><div class="img">any image</div><div class="views">1234 views</div></td>                
                <td><div class="img">any image</div><div class="views">890 views</div></td>             
                <td><div class="img">any image</div><div class="views">789 views</div></td>             
            </tr>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set the css property of container () to position:relative  then you need to set

```
td {position:relative;}  <-- this will need some tweaking by class or id
.img { position:absolute; top:0px;  border: 1px solid blue;height: 85%;}
.views {position:absolute; bottom:0px;height: 15%;border: 1px solid green;}
```

you might also consider adding a div container inside the TD for the position:relative;  part

Comment: Any problem adding the relative position to td instead of creating another div? Thanks for the reply tho

Comment: well the way I did it, the position:relative is applied to any TD on the page and that may not have the effect you are looking for.  At the very least I would recommend adding a class to the TD and apply the position:relative to the class with something like td.classname {position:relative};

Comment: oh yea, i actually have something like this on my css **article#article-top td {}** So probably won't affect all td, right?

Comment: Same idea.  You would want to do the same thing to this table.